# Data model for a BI dashboard

Tags: database, powerbi, data-modeling, business-intelligence, entity-relationship

I am hoping to get some help on the data model design of a dashboard I am building. I think it should be fairly straight forward, but I want to be sure I am doing this right.

Currently I have just three tables in a simple star schema layout:

- Client table
- Location table (Clients have multiple locations)
- Metrics table for monthly billing

[Data model visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVPXA.png)

Now, I want to create some new fields based on the monthly data in the Billing_Metrics table. There are more but this should give an idea of what I am looking for. I would like to track these at both the client and location level:

- Three, six, and twelve month averages for units sold and revenue.
- Percentage change from previous month to current month for units sold and revenue.
- Flags that would indicate things such as a client (or location) that had charges in the previous month, but has zero for the current month.

Ok, so the question is where the best place for these new fields in the data model would be and how should they be joined to the current structure? I can’t work it out in my head how that would look, especially when it needs to be at both the client and location level. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add these metrics to the table. Since you have "PowerBI" tag, I assume you plan to use Power BI as a reporting tool. Such tools allow you to calculate complex metrics dynamically (in PowerBI case, using language called "DAX" - Data Analysis Expressions). Such dynamic metrics automatically recalculate based on your report layouts and filters, including any combinations of locations, clients and dates. You can get a sense of the capabilities here:

[Measures in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/)

In general, keywords you need are:

- Star Schema
- Dimensional Modeling
- Ralph Kimball, Bill Inmon
- PowerBI, DAX, calculated measures

Note:

- You are missing a ["Calendar"](https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/calendar-table-explained/) table in your model.
- If you are using PowerBI, remove primary key from your "Metrics" table. It will bloat the size of your model dramatically, while providing no analytical value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, RADO! Are there any drawbacks to using DAX measures within PowerBI? Such as performance when scaling up? Someone I work with brought up this concern and suggested these metrics should be calculated within SQL Server and then fed into PowerBI via a View. I'm just learning much of this so I'm not sure if there is any truth to that.

Thank you for the other tips! I will work on correcting those two pieces.

Comment: DAX measures are essentially dynamic queries (DAX is translated into xmSQL statements in the background). The big advantage is that measures remain responsive to "context", which can be modifed interactively by users. If you use precalculated metrics, you will largerly lose this capability, which I think is the most attractive feature of PowerBI. Performance depends on measures complexity and data size. Your metrics are trivial, so complexity isn't a problem. For the size, you shouldn't have any issues until 1 billion records (assuming your star schema is correct and DAX is written properly).

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you again!